# Appended script not being executed

Tags: javascript, html, sql, ajax

I'm attempting to import an external script to the header of an HTML file. The name of the script should be fetched from a SQL datatable which will be updated regularly (thus, different scripts will get imported). To do so, I set up a XMLHttpRequest, within the function I set js = to the text taken from the SQL datatable, finally, I append the new js to the top of my header. I assumed this would do the trick, however, the script doesn't seem to be successfully imported. For instance, if I console log the variable 'cond' from the appropriate script then I get an error. So my question is why doesn't the script get executed and what can I do to fix it?

**script3.js**

```
var cond = "hallo"
```

**index.html**

```
<script src="script1.js"></script>
<script src="script2.js"></script>

<script>  //import script with name taken from SQL database 

    function reqListener () {
      console.log(this.responseText);
    }

    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest(); // New request object. 
    oReq.onload = function() {
        const js = document.createElement("script");
        var noQuotes = this.responseText.split('"').join('');
        js.src = noQuotes;
        document.head.appendChild(js);  //script should now have been appended to top of head 

    };


    oReq.open("get", "index.php", true);
    oReq.send();
</script>

<script>
console.log(cond). //attept to console log variable from imported js file 
</script>
```

Comment: _..then I get an error..._ What error?

Comment: your appended `<script>` is inside another `<script>`

Comment: What is `this.responseText`?

Comment: the error I'm getting: "Uncaught ReferenceError: cond is not defined"

Comment: this.responseText is the content of the cell being fetched from the SQL table

Comment: and yes vanowm, I forgot to add a </script>! Adding it didn't fix the problem tho

Comment: You need an `onload` for the inserted script element before you can access `cond`. The file needs to load and be compiled first

Comment: what exactly would the onload statement look like and where would I put it?

Comment: `js.onload = function(){ console.log(cond);}`

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the `"Uncaught ReferenceError: cond is not defined"` because the `cond` variable is not defined... yet!

You want to wrap `console.log(cond)` [with an `onload` event handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) ... so that your html document waits for the `js` variable to fully load before trying to execute that command.

Something like:

```
<script src="script1.js"></script>
<script src="script2.js"></script>

<script>  //import script with name taken from SQL database 

    function reqListener () {
      console.log(this.responseText);
    }

    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest(); // New request object.

    let js = document.createElement("script");

    oReq.onload = function() {
        var noQuotes = this.responseText.split('"').join('');
        js.src = noQuotes;
        document.head.appendChild(js);  //script should now have been appended to top of head 

    };


    oReq.open("get", "index.php", true);
    oReq.send();

    js.onload = function() {
      console.log(cond)
    };
</script>
```

Should work. (Provided you bring the js variable into the global scope... aka, declare it outside of the `oReq.onload` function.

> To do so, I set up a XMLHttpRequest

P.S. Check out [the Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) instead of XMLHttpRequest. Much cleaner.

Comment: window.onload is likely to occur before that script element is loaded due to the ajax. `js.onload` would make more sense